# sorting algorithm boundary proof

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Based on this slide:
http://oi48.tinypic.com/27xmg47.jpg

Q1> why `N!` different orderings `=>` at least `N!` leaves?

Q2> why `#leaves >= N!`?

The reason why 2^h >= #leaves is that 2^h represents the number of leaves in a complete binary tree and #leave is most time come from an incomplete binary tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `N!` different orderings. The algorithm has to determine exactly, which ordering is present and therefore its decision tree has to have at least `N!` leaves. Otherwise, it would not be able to distinguish all possible orderings.